# Getting products for category

Tags: java, comparative-review, rx-java

I have a PR for a bugfix in which the fix is just 4 characters. In this situation we are invited to make some refactoring on the class that we are touching if possible.

Venkat Subramaniam's advice is to [make lambda expressions just one line](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java8idioms6/index.html), hence I'm trying to move a block of code in a method.

Now choosing a better name come to the scene, and the challenge is to use `For+ParamName` or not use it on the method name.

With this advice from Google folks ([Code Health: IdentifierNamingPostForWorldWideWebBlog](https://testing.googleblog.com/2017/10/code-health-identifiernamingpostforworl.html)):

> Omit words that are clear from the surrounding context.

I think that a method name `getProducts(Category category)` is better than `getProductsForCategory(Category category)`, so could we avoid the `For+ParamName`?

#### Before

```
public class ProductProvider {

private final ProductProviderDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public ProductProvider(ProductProviderDatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
    this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
}

public Observable<List<Product>> getProductsForCategory(Category category) {
    if (category == null) {
        return Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            // DAO code
            result = daoProduct.query(preparedQuery);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error retrieving Products");
        }

        return Observable.just(result);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

#### After

```
public class ProductProvider {

private final ProductProviderDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public ProductProvider(ProductProviderDatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
    this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
}

public Observable<List<Product>> getProductsForCategory(Category category) {
    if (category == null) {
        return Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    return Observable.defer(() -> getProducts(category)
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Comment: while talking about refactoring, in your last `return` statement I would move the closing bracket before `subscribeOn` to the line above because it closes the parameters for `defer`.

Comment: indeed I tried to do it but I didn't due to SO editor (maybe I did it in the wrong way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method name `getProducts` looks like a getter. However, there is some logic inside and getters usually don't have arguments. `getProducts(Category category)` seems a bit suspicious for me.

The name `getProductsForCategory(Category category)` looks too verbose: *category* is present three times. Why not calling it `getProductsFor(Category category)`? There would be no repetition and it is read straightforward.

To avoid the confusion with a getter, I also think that it could be named `filterProductsBy(Category category)` or `retrieveProductsFor(Category category)`.

Comment: I like the `filterProductsBy` idea, although the `getProducts` sounds concise to me as well. Methods are overloadable, so `getProducts()` without parameter could return every product, `getProducts(category)` would return the products of that category and maybe `getProducts(productName)` would return any product of that name.